# Run different cron jobs on different time

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I have two cron jobs, first one should be executed every minutes and the second one should be done every two minutes.

In my crontab file

```
*/1 * * * * /home/fileserver/Desktop/Test/DBBackgrounder.exe;
*/2 * * * * echo "Date Successfully Updated: $(date)" >> /var/log/DBBackgrounder.log
```

I tried this but both jobs run every minute.

Comment: probably not relevant, but don't you need a space between '*' and 'echo'?

Comment: There must be a typo in `*/2 * * * *ec`. Also, every minute would be ok to be written as `* * * * * command`.

Comment: @ Dan Pichelman - Yes, it's just typo. Both jobs run every minute.

Comment: Semicolons in crontabs are used to chain together commands, but the new line should identify it as a finished line.  I'd remove it though and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @ fedorqui - Thank you for the tip! but how can i make the two jobs run on different interval time?

Comment: Just to check all bases, DBBackgrounder.exe doesn't also write out to the log file, does it?

Comment: (To mention someone, use `@` and `nick` all together). Try what @miah suggests. Also, perform a very simple test `* * * * * touch /tmp/one` and `*/2 * * * * touch /tmp/two`.

Comment: @ miah - I removed the semicolons and it works fine! Thank you everyone!